# Cannot compile system module with Swift 4.1 Package Manager on Ubuntu

Tags: swift, linux, ubuntu, swift-package-manager

When I am trying to compile libavutil via Swift Package Manager, `swift build` returns an error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: unexpected 'commands' value (expected map)
<unknown>:0: error: unable to load build file
```

---

#### Project files:

Package.swift:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "CAVUtil",
    pkgConfig: "libavutil-ffmpeg"
)
```

module.modulemap

```
module CAVUtil [system] {
    header "avutil.h"
    link "avutil"
    export *
}
```

avutil.h

```
#ifndef _CAVUtil_H_
#define _CAVUtil_H_

#include <libavutil/avutil.h>

#endif
```

---

Swift, Ubuntu:

```
swift --version
Swift version 4.1 (swift-4.1-RELEASE)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

pkg-config --version
0.29.1

Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```